# Making portable Nodes in Django and using them to make Trees

Tags: python, django, django-models

What I am trying to make is something that can be done quite simply using pointers in `C++`. The idea is this, I have an object, and it is called a `Node`. This node will have a couple of characteristics:

1. It is connected to other nodes, through parents and children.
2. It can be transplanted, it can be ported, meaning that I can take this Node, and stick it anywhere I want, it can be another tree, or I can use this Node to start a new tree altogether.

Also, this means, that you can create a whole tree using nodes. Ideally a tree will be a collection of nodes that have one central greatest-grand-parent.

However, a Node can have two or even more parents.

Comment: Without third-party libraries it will take some time... Anyway, looking at these libs will be helpful: [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt), [django-treebeard](https://github.com/tabo/django-treebeard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easily doable, but I wouldn't recommend it in terms of performance:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('YourModel', related_name='children')

    def siblings(self):
        return self.objects.filter(parent=self.parent_id).exclude(pk=self.pk)
```

Usage:

```
some_child = YourModel.objects.get(...)
siblings = some_child.siblings()
parent = some_child.parent()
children = parent.children.all()
```

The question is really, what do you want to do?

Comment: i prefer to use this syntax, to my mind it is more clear: `parent = models.ForeignKey('self', ...)`

Comment: @stalk: where would `self` come from, it's not in the scope as it is?

Comment: ah, forgot to put `self` in `''`. Updated now, here is docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: Thank you for this. I am trying to create a tree, but it seems that django does not have anything inbuilt to facilitate that, and one would need to use a third-party library. Also, as you mentioned this is a drag on performance.

Comment: I will update my question shortly. Thanks for the support so far.

Comment: As stalk already mentioned, if it's about building a tree than using a library is not a bad idea. Is there any reason for not wanting to use libraries? The libraries are part of what makes Django such a powerful framework, for pretty much anything there is a library available.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: in that case I think my answer should do pretty much what you want, depending how you query however, it might not be the fastest solution. If you want to query these things in a fast way a recursive query in postgres could be very helpful btw. Alternatively a graph database could work. Or within Django, here's a little list of libraries which do roughly what you want: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/trees-and-graphs/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check third-party [django-categories](https://github.com/callowayproject/django-categories) which provide hierarchical taxonomy management system. You can create nodes and stick it to others to create trees (with parent-children relathionship)